# Prove that $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^2}{x^4+5x^2+4}dx = \frac{\pi}{6}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, residue-calculus

> Prove that $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^2}{x^4+5x^2+4}dx = \frac{\pi}{6}$

Obviously you would use Residue Theorem to tackle this problem.  The correct answer to this is $\frac{\pi}{6}$ however I'm not getting the same result.  Here's what I've done so far:

Since $x^2$ is an even function we know that we can therefore split this into two parts. We know there's a singularity at $i$, $-i$ and $2i$, $-2i$.  So we just take the limit of $R$ tending to infinity of the integral $-R$ to $R$ of $\frac{x^2}{(x^4+5x^2+4)}$.  However, this means you would have to integrate around the singularities, right?  After this, I'm not entirely sure what to do.

Comment: Mildly interesting partial fractions approach: $${x^2\over x^4+5x^2+4}=\frac {x^2}3\left(\frac 1{x^2+1}-\frac 1{x^2+4}\right)$$

Comment: @mathlove I know that but I want to know how to do it with the theorem.

Answer (score 3):

The contour looks like this:

[image]

For each $R>2$, we have by the residue theorem that

$$
\oint_C f(z)dz = 2\pi i(\text{Res}[f,i]+\text{Res}[f,2i])
$$  To compute the residues, use the factor-and-cover trick:

$$
f(z) = \frac{z^2}{(z+i)(z-i)(z+2i)(z-2i)}
$$ so

$$
\text{Res}[f,i] = \lim_{z\rightarrow i} (z-i)f(z) = \frac{i^2}{(i+i)(i+2i)(i-2i)} = \frac{i}{6}\\
\text{Res}[f,2i] = \lim_{z\rightarrow 2i} (z-2i)f(z) = \frac{(2i)^2}{(2i+i)(2i-i)(2i+2i)} = \frac{-i}{3}
$$ Thus

$$
2\pi i(\text{Res}[f,i]+\text{Res}[f,2i]) = 2\pi i\left(\frac{i}{6}-\frac{i}{3}\right) = -2\pi i \frac{i}{6} = \frac{\pi}{3}
$$  This is *twice* the integral you want, so your integral is $\pi/6$.  The only thing I didn't show is that the integral over the radial part goes to 0 in the limit as $R\rightarrow\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Take the semicircle with radius $R$ that lays in the upper half plane. As $R \to \infty$, since the integral over the circle is going to zero, you will be left with 2 times the integral you're seeking.

Which singularities do you encounter? All the singularities in the upper half plane, hence $i$ and $2i$.

So calculate the residue in $i$ and $2i$, show that the integral over the "curve" part of the semicircle goes to $0$, and apply the residue theorem

P.S. it works because your whole function is even, not just $x^2$. Had you had something like $\frac {x^2}{x^3 + 5}$ this would not work :-)

Comment: Can you perhaps show the residue part in more detail?  I understand everything you said about singularities.

Comment: @cambelot The integral you seek is Integral over real line + integral over circle, and thanks to the residue theorem is equal to  $2 \pi i $ times the sum of residue. Now since as $R \to \infty$ the integral over the circle vaniches, you have Integral over real line = $2 \pi i $ times the sum of residues. So find the residue at the singularities and you're done. Do you know how to find the residue there?

Comment: I think I do but that's where I feel like my calculations got messed up.

Comment: @cambelot edit your answer and report your calculations them. Maybe check them again :D